# Where do I install non-end user commands?

Tags: directory-structure

In a project of mine I have a couple of specialized commands which are only called by other commands, and are not supposed to be invoked by the end user. Should these internal commands be installed in PREFIX/bin or are they better installed somewhere else, for instance in PREFIX/lib?

Edit: The internal commands in question are all Awk scripts. Since they are architecture independent I consider installing them in PREFIX/share/PACKAGE-NAME/bin. Would that be a good choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) says this,

> /bin contains commands that may be used by both the system
>   administrator and by users, but which are required when no other
>   filesystems are mounted (e.g. in single user mode). It may also
>   contain commands which are used indirectly by scripts.

and

> The /lib directory contains those shared library images needed to boot
>   the system and run the commands in the root filesystem, ie. by
>   binaries in /bin  and /sbin.

and,

> Utilities  used  for  system  administration  (and  other  root-only 
>   commands)  are  stored  in  /sbin,  /usr/sbin, and /usr/local/sbin. 
>   /sbin contains binaries essential for booting, restoring, recovering,
>   and/or repairing the system in addition to the binaries in /bin.
>   Programs executed after /usr is knownto  be  mounted  (when  there 
>   are  no  problems)  are  generally  placed  into  /usr/sbin. 
>   Locally-installed system administration programs should be placed into
>   /usr/local/sbin.

Finally,

> /usr/lib includes object files and libraries. On some systems, it may
>   also include internal binaries that are not intended to be executed
>   directly by users or shell scripts. Applications may use a single
>   subdirectory under  /usr/lib. If an application uses a subdirectory,
>   all architecture-dependent data exclusively used by the application
>   must be placed within that subdirectory.

There's obviously `/usr/bin`, and a number of other options.  Your definition to me, feels most like `/usr/lib`.

Comment: `/usr/lib` indeed. See `git` for an example of this.

Comment: The internal commands in question are Awk scripts and not binaries. Since they are architecture independent, maybe PREFIX/share is a better alternative.

Comment: @StephenKitt I looked in `/usr/lib/git-core/` and it contains several shell scripts. Therefor I assume it's okay to put architecture independent scripts in PREFIX/lib/PACKAGE-NAME.

Comment: @August yes, you can put arch-independent files in `/usr/lib/.../`. Think of the definition as being a restriction: *only* arch-independent files can go in `/usr/share`, there is no such restriction for `/usr/lib`. For commands it’s often easier to go with `/usr/lib`, it avoids having to move things around if you ever switch from a script to a binary.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Linux FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html), chapter [4.11](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html):

> The /usr/share hierarchy is for all read-only architecture independent
>   data files.

However, you should probably use `/usr/libexec/` or `/usr/local/libexec/`, as per FHS' recommendations (chapter [4.7](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s07.html)):

> /usr/libexec includes internal binaries that are not intended to be
>   executed directly by users or shell scripts. Applications may use a
>   single subdirectory under /usr/libexec.
>
> Applications which use /usr/libexec in this way must not also use
>   /usr/lib to store internal binaries, though they may use /usr/lib for
>   the other purposes documented here.

Comment: The executables in question are Awk scripts and not *binaries*, that's why I think `lib` or `libexec` is not the right choice.